# Why is the first query always skipped and the sorting doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP to get data from a form with 2 drop downs and a radio button. The idea is that the values from the drop down determine the order by of the query (order by field ASC or DESC). However the second query in the code is the only one executed even when the radio button selects 1 and the ORDER BY parameters are not being correctly passed using the PHP variables. I hope someone cal help me spotting what is wrong, I have tried with isset and without it, so far no joy.

```
database connect and select is done here...

$sortIn = $_POST['SortOrder'];
$sortBy = $_POST['OrderBy'];
$include = $_POST['Include'];

if (isset($include) && $include = "0")
{
    $myquery = 'SELECT something FROM somewhere ORDER BY "$OrderBy" "$SortOrder"' ;
    $answer=mysql_query($myquery);
    if (!$answer) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $myquery;
        die($message);
        }

    echo "some HTML"

    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($answer))
    {
echo "some HTML";
}

elseif (isset($include) && $include = "1")
    {
     $myquerytwo = 'SELECT * FROM Results ORDER BY "$OrderBy" "$SortOrder"' ;
     $answertwo=mysql_query($myquerytwo);
     if (!$answertwo) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $myquerytwo;
    die($message);
        }
        echo "some HTML";

    while($resulttwo=mysql_fetch_array($answertwo))
    {
echo "Some HTML";
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML form also

Answer (score 2):

Your conditionals are not set right :)

You have:

```
$include = "0"
```

Which is just going to set $include to 0 and always return true since the assignment will suceed.

Change it to:

```
$include == "0"
```

Do that for your other conditional as well.

I'll also take a moment to let you know that the mysql_* library is deprecated and should no longer be used. I recommend using the mysqli set. It's the most like mysql_*, and easy to switch over to: [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is the documentation.

Have some sort order:

```
"SELECT something FROM somewhere ORDER BY '$OrderBy' $SortOrder"
```

Comment: nice nickname ;) Thx for the tips. I know mysql is deprecated but I am following an introduction course based on mysql...this work will not be online, it is just for a simple demo. Thanks again!

Comment: can you spot why the order by doesn't work?
$myquerytwo = 'SELECT * FROM Results ORDER BY "$OrderBy" "$SortOrder"'

Comment: Ahh one of the online tutorials, you using w3schools? Now, as for your order by not working, well, you're not using variable substitution right. Assuming that $OrderBy will always be a valid column name and $SortOrder will always be the values ASC or DESC just switch what you're using to delimit your string. In PHP, by default using " to delimit a string tells the interpreter "sup brah, variables be here" and your variables will be placed inside. Single's don't. That said, wrap the whole query string inside " and wrap the $OrderBy in ' then nothing around $SortOrder and that should do it